# React MUI TextField Multiple select (uncontrolled input)

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, textfield

I Have a Field that supposed to get some data from DB (editComponent), when it is selected one item it's works fine, but when selected multiple it's not showing anything. How to insert selected values in this field?
im using formData instead of useState and just grabbing all inputs.

```
<TextField
  id="project_scope_id"
  name="project_scope"
  label="Select Scope"
  select
  defaultValue={inputData?.project_scope ?? []}
  SelectProps={{
    multiple: true
  }}
>
  {scope.map((scope) => (
    <MenuItem key={scope} value={scope}>
      {scope}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

I'm trying getting rid of useState in this component, when I was using setState in lieu of formData everything worked fine....